# How to join AND sum values of two columns?

Tags: sql, join

I have the following two tables

TeamsTable

| TeamID | TeamName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Name1 |
| 2 | Name2 |
| 3 | Name3 |
| ... | ... |

and

GameScoresTable

| GameID | HomeTeam(FK) | AwayTeam(FK) | HomeTeamScore | AwayTeamScore |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 50 | 60 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | 70 | 80 |
| 3 | 3 | 4 | 70 | 80 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

I want to get a table like this:

FinalTable

| GameID | HomeTeam | AwayTeam | TotalScore |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Name1 | Name2 | 110 |
| 2 | Name2 | Name3 | 150 |
| 3 | Name3 | Name4 | 150 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

I tried the following query, but it doesn't work.

```
SELECT 
GameScores.GameID
,TeamH.TeamName as HomeTeam
,TeamA.TeamName as AwayTeam
,SUM(GameScores.HomeTeamScore + GameScores.AwayTeamScore)
FROM GameScores 
    INNER JOIN Teams TeamH ON GameScores.HomeTeam=TeamH.TeamID
    INNER JOIN Teams TeamA ON GameScores.AwayTeam=TeamA.TeamID
    GROUP   BY GameID
```

Essentially, I want to get the HomeTeam and AwayTeam columns to show their proper names rather than the foreign key value and want the last column to show their combined score.

Comment: I don't see "Name4" in your sample data, and what does "but it doesn't work" actually mean?

Comment: I missed adding ... so it is clear the tables is actually longer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to aggregate your data. Just use `+` to get the sum.

```
SELECT 
     GameScores.GameID
    ,TeamH.TeamName AS HomeTeam
    ,TeamA.TeamName AS AwayTeam
    ,GameScores.HomeTeamScore + GameScores.AwayTeamScore AS totalscore
FROM GameScores 
    INNER JOIN Teams TeamH ON GameScores.HomeTeam=TeamH.TeamID
    INNER JOIN Teams TeamA ON GameScores.AwayTeam=TeamA.TeamID
```